# Is it acceptable to align a single element vertically using flexbox?

Tags: html, css

I see flexbox is so useful not only in organizing a whole page layout but even on smaller scale.

For example, to vertically align a single element inside a div i can do that:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Is it a bad practice to do that and to use flexbox in many rules generally? , is it bad for performance to overuse it??

Comment: No it is not bad practice, this is a very efficient way to align things, also flexbox is supported on most major browsers - see [here](https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)

Comment: Thanks! yes it is a very efficient way!!

Comment: It's very useful for instance when you have to center something both vertically and horizontally at the same time, you can simply assign flex to the container and `margin: auto;` to the child element.